# Why does a count formula return 0 when the range of cells are linked to another sheet?

Tags: excel

I am trying to count a range of cells that have text in and ignore 0 that is in some of these cells. All of these cells have a link to another cell sheet within the same workbook and so are returning 0 if the linked cell has nothing entered. I have tried COUNTIF, COUNTA and SUMPRODUCT but all return 0

Answer (score 1):

Assume data housed in `A1:A10`

`B1`, enter formula :

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"?*")
```